# Laravel 4 Eloquent Model Inside loop

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I wonder how to handle this. So I have a model:

```
class myModel extends Eloquent {

// assuming I have the proper codes here

}
```

And in my services lets say I have this code:

```
Class myService 
{

    protected myModel;

    public function __construct(myModel $myModel)
    {
       $this->myModel = $myModel;
    }

    public function saveManyTimes()
    {
        // assuming i have to loop here for something that needs to be
        // save many times
        $x = 0;
        $y = 5;
        while($x < $y){

          $this->myModel->name = 'joe';
          $this->myModel->age  = 19;
          $this->myModel->save();

        }

    }

}
```

Now my question is, in saveManyTimes method, as you can see, it has a loop that saves
upto 5x. But the output is the only first iteration is save. Why is Eloquent behaving like that? How do you handle that?

But When I try to change the code to:

```
        // note I use **new**
        $x = 0;
        $y = 5;
        while($x < $y){

          $myModel = new myModel();
          $myModel->name = 'joe';
          $myModel->age  = 19;
          $myModel->save();

        }
```

This works great, it saves the data 5x. But I don't want to do it that way for I don't want to call "new" everywhere, in my service, because it's killing Dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

When you inject myModel into the __construct you are basically creating a new myModel. But the __construct is only called when you instantiate myService, so only one time. If you want to inject the model in the __construct you will have to instantiate myService 5 times with new myService and only save one time in the function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the "create" method. This should I be calling instead of "save" method in a loop cases. so it will be $this->myModel->create(array of attr); inside the loop. Thanks for the reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, in my service:

```
Class myService 
{

    protected myModel;

    public function __construct(myModel $myModel)
    {
       $this->myModel = $myModel;
    }

    public function saveManyTimes()
    {

        $x = 0;
        $y = 5;
        while($x < $y){

          // instead of doing this
          $this->myModel->name = 'joe';
          $this->myModel->age  = 19;
          $this->myModel->save();

          // this should be this way when inside a loop cases
          $this->myModel->create(array(
            'name' => 'joe',
            'age' => 19
          ));


        }

    }

}
```